# Choosing a function inside an integral so as to remove the dependence on a particular variable

Tags: integration

So I have a slightly strange situation where I am considering:

$$\int_t^y \exp\left(-\frac{(g(x)-g(t))^2}{4(x-t)}\right) \frac{ f(y,x)}{\sqrt{x-t}}dx$$

where g is some given function and $f(y,x)$ is completely arbitrary. What I would like to be able to do is choose a form for $f(y,x)$ such that this integral no longer depends on y. It seems to me that this should always be possible, although perhaps it isn't, but if it is I can't work out a way to find what $f(y,x)$ needs to be.

Comment: Is $t$ fixed or variable?  Are you assuming $y \ge t$?  Your $f$ and $g$ can't really be completely arbitrary, because you want the integral to exist (perhaps as an improper Riemann integral).  What differentiability assumptions are you willing to make?

Comment: You can certainly take $f(y,x) = 0$, but I suppose you want less trivial solutions.

Comment: Yes, t is fixed and $y>t$. OK yeah they can't be completely arbitrary as the integral does have to exist. g would most likely be a well behaved continuous function, and providing the integral exists it's not really that important what f is, but I would like to choose it such that the result of the integral will not have any y dependence.